# HDD detected in BIOS with bad S.M.A.R.T. but not in windows disk management

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I have an old Maxtor STM3250310AS. I want to copy its data to my current HDD as it is damaged (not physically).

I connected it to SATA while Windows 7 was running. HDD started spinning but windows didn't detect it. I shutdown PC and turned on again. After remaining for a long time in post screen, it said "S.M.A.R.T. Status Bad, Backup and Replace". BIOS settings shows drive information (serial number, manufacturer,...) correctly.
I started windows again to read S.M.A.R.T. info but disk isn't available at all. I checked both device manager and disk management.

Is there any solution to read S.M.A.R.T. data at least to identify the problem? Why windows doesn't detect this HDD while BIOS does?

Comment: Don't connect SATA with the machine powered on. It *theoretically* supports hot-swapping, but needs *all* the hardware to be compliant. Home PCs are rarely compliant.

Comment: @Tetsujin Sorry. I should explain better. By restart I mean shut down and start.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to avoid Windows being able to read the SMART data at all. Connect it via a USB drive dock & SMART won't pass to the computer. This doesn't mean the drive will improve, but Windows won't hard block it.

Comment: @Tetsujin You mean windows itself blocks HDD? I don't have a USB drive dock. What about Linux? Does it work? I'll test using a live USB (peppermint or linuxmint) soon.

Comment: Having the drive connected directly to the SATA bus on the computer means that the SMART data can be read. If BIOS is locking it out even before you get to any running OS, the only way round it is to remove the SMART communication. USB is the simplest way to achieve this.

Comment: Using Linux is a great idea if to have the knowledge - (booting a USB install if appropriate) and using ddrescue is my go-to method of doing a bit copy of a failing drive - but it does require a modicum of knowledge and care to ensure you get the drive identifiers correct and don't write data in the wrong direction.

Comment: Try looking up `ddrescue`, it might be a good tool for your use-case -  if your drive is damaged, the last thing you want is Windows writing *anything* to it. Your best bet is creating an image and doing digital forensics on it if browsing for the files isn't possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally read S.M.A.R.T. using Linux. Seems that Windows ignores badly damaged HDDs even if you disable S.M.A.R.T. in BIOS.

Disable Memory Hole in BIOS and boot to a Linux OS distribution live USB (mine: Peppermint OS 10). In Disks app> menu> SMART Data & self tests (look [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/528077/677636)), enabled the switch if is disabled (enables S.M.A.R.T. for this HDD) and it shows parameters after a few seconds.

Main problem was "Seek Error Rate" for my HDD. I still can read data with a very low speed from disk using file manager (Nemo for Peppermint OS).